# accuracy calculation for a binary classification regression model

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, cross-entropy

can someone tell me why my cross entropy Loss function giving this error:

My accuracy method:

```
def accuracy(outputs, labels):
    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
    return torch.tensor(torch.sum(preds == labels).item() / len(preds))
```

My class defining the model:

```
class PulsarLogisticRegression(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear= nn.Linear(input_size,output_size)
    def forward(self,xb):
        xb = xb.view(xb.size(0), -1)
        out= self.linear(xb)
        return out
    def training_step(self, batch):
        inputs, targets = batch 
        # Generate predictions
        out = self(inputs)          
        # Calcuate loss
        loss = F.cross_entropy(out,targets)                         
        return loss
    def validation_step(self, batch):
        inputs, targets = batch
        # Generate predictions
        out = self(inputs)
        # Calculate loss
        loss = F.cross_entropy(out,targets)
        acc = accuracy(out, targets)        # Calculate accuracy
        return {'val_loss': loss, 'val_acc': acc} # fill this    
    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        batch_losses = [x['val_loss'] for x in outputs]
        epoch_loss = torch.stack(batch_losses).mean()   # Combine losses
        batch_accs = [x['val_acc'] for x in outputs]
        epoch_acc = torch.stack(batch_accs).mean()      # Combine accuracies
        return {'val_loss': epoch_loss.item(), 'val_acc': epoch_acc.item()}
   def epoch_end(self, epoch, result, num_epochs):
        # Print result every 20th epoch
        print("Epoch [{}], val_loss: {:.4f}, val_acc: {:.4f}".format(epoch, result['val_loss'], result['val_acc']))
```

error: Cross Entropy Error is expecting 1D target tensor but multi-target is bieng assigned to it.

```
 RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-cd9b8a9a3b02> in <module>()
----> 1 result = evaluate(model, val_loader) # Use the the evaluate function
      2 print(result) 4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2262                          .format(input.size(0), target.size(0)))
   2263     if dim == 2:
-> 2264         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2265     elif dim == 4:
   2266         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss2d(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
 

RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
```

I am very new to Machine Learning, I am trying to make a model which predicts one column of data based on 5 columns. The values in the column are 0 and 1. So it is basically a binary classification model.

What I tried:
As I said I am fairly new to this field, some explanations suggest to use squeeze function to somehow reduce the shape of target tensor to 1D but that seems to throw some other errors in other methods of the class.

I am looking for an error function which would help me get correct accuracy.